# What is wrong with my SQL here? #1089 - Incorrect prefix key

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `table`.`users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `dir` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`(11))
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

I'm getting the `#1089 - Incorrect prefix key` error and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Remove `(11)` from your primary key declaration -- you should just use the column, in this case, `id`...  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30aa3/1

Comment: if you're using PHPMyAdmin, leave the size value empty on the pop-up window.

Answer (score 111):

In your PRIMARY KEY definition you've used `(id(11))`, which defines a prefix key - i.e. the first 11 characters only should be used to create an index. Prefix keys are only valid for `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `BINARY` and `VARBINARY` types and your `id` field is an `int`, hence the error.

Use `PRIMARY KEY (id)` instead and you should be fine.

MySQL reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) and read from paragraph 4.

Answer (score 26):

If you are using a GUI and you are still getting the same problem. Just leave the size value empty, the primary key defaults the value to 11, you should be fine with this. Worked with Bitnami phpmyadmin.

Comment: Not the "primary key", but `INT SIGNED` defaults to a size `(11)`.

Answer (score 12):

This

> PRIMARY KEY (`id` (11))

is generated automatically by phpmyadmin, change to

> PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

.

Answer (score 7):

There is a simple way of doing it. This may not be the expert answer and it may not work for everyone but it did for me.

Uncheck all primary and unique check boxes, jut create a plain simple table.

When phpmyadmin (or other) shows you the table structure, make the column **primary** by the given button.

Then click on **change** and edit the settings of that or other colums like 'unique' etc.

Answer (score 7):

```
CREATE TABLE `table`.`users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `dir` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`(11))
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Change To

```
CREATE TABLE `table`.`users` (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `dir` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 6):

**Here the full solution step by step**

- First of all you have to make the table by inserting all the data. id should AI ticked.
- then press go and #1089 error will be pop-up

**here is the solution**

- theres a button near go called preview SQL
- click that button and copy the sql code
- then click on SQL tab on top of the window
- Clear the text filed and paste that copied code there.
- you will be see `(id (11))` this on bottom of the code
- replace `(id (11))` into `(id)`
- and click go

**boom now you will be fine**

Answer (score 4):

In my case, i faced the problem while creating table from phpmyadmin. For id column i choose the primary option from index dropdown and filled the size 10.

If you're using phpmyadmin, to solve this problem change the index dropdown option again, after reselecting the primary option again it'll ask you the size, leave it blank and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE `users`(
    `user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to just write a code answer without explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Problem is the same for me in phpMyAdmin. I just created a table without any const. 
Later I modified the ID to a Primary key. Then I changed the ID to Auto-inc. 
That solved the issue.

```
ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `ID` `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you give id as a primary key then a pop up is come and those aske you to how many size of this primary key.
So you just leave blank because by default int value is set 11. Click then ok on those pop up without any enter a number.
in this type of error never will you face in future.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same problem. 
Solution work for me:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `sr_no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `dir` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sr_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

I paste this code in SQL and run, it works fine.

Comment: what is `sr_no`??

Answer (score 1):

In PHPMyAdmin, Ignore / leave the size value empty on the pop-up window.

Answer (score 0):

according to the latest version of MySQL (phpMyAdmin), add a correct INDEX while choosing primary key. for example: id[int] INDEX 0 ,if id is your primary key and at the first index. 
**Or,**

---

For your problem try this one

```
CREATE TABLE `table`.`users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `dir` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Comment: May be useful here to state what the latest version actually is?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `table`.`users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `dir` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`(id))
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

No need to put `id(11)` because, by default, it is equal to 11 so you leave
it as `id` and in `phpmyadmin` you leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `table`.`user` and just use `user`
The lenght of the `id` was alread specified in the
`id` INT(11) and does not need to be specified in the PRIMART KEY.

CREATE TABLE `users`
(
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`dir` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

) ENGINE = MyISAM;