# #1089 Error when creating table in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

While creating a table I'm getting error #1089- Incorrect Prefix Key.

My sql code :

```
CREATE TABLE `buildblockz`.`db_user_info` ( `BBZUID` INT(11) UNSIGNED   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'User''s Id' , `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s username' , `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s password' , `fname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s First Name' , `mname` VARCHAR(255) NULL COMMENT 'User''s Middle Name' , `lname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s Last Name' , `line1` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s Address Line 1' , `line2` VARCHAR(255) NULL COMMENT 'User''s Address Line 2' , `city` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s Address City' , `state` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s Address State' , `pincode` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s Address Pincode' , `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s Contact Email' , `mobile` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'User''s Contact Mobile' , `phone` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT 'User''s Contact Phone' , `sex` ENUM('M','F','NS') NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s Sex' , `dateOfBirth` DATE NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s Date of Birth' , `designation` VARCHAR(255) NULL COMMENT 'User''s Designation' , `dateOfEntry` TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'User''s Date of Entry' , PRIMARY KEY (`BBZUID`(9)) , UNIQUE (`username`(30)) ) ENGINE = InnoDB COMMENT = 'User''s Database';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is wrong with my SQL here? #1089 - Incorrect prefix key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932281/what-is-wrong-with-my-sql-here-1089-incorrect-prefix-key)

Comment: Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932281/what-is-wrong-with-my-sql-here-1089-incorrect-prefix-key

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to remove the length of the key:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`BBZUID`) ,
```

instead of

```
PRIMARY KEY (`BBZUID`(9)) ,
```

Comment: Thanx, can you give me the reason.

Comment: Because the column `BBZUID` is of type int. keys with langht is only provided by columns of type varchar and char.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens.. I was stuck for quite a while

Answer (score 2):

SQL code

instead of `primary key('id'(10));`

it would be `primary key('id');`

Answer (score 1):

1. go to preview SQL
2. copy SQL syntax
3. change this part of SQL syntax:

   PRIMARY KEY (`BBZUID`(9)) ->  PRIMARY KEY (`BBZUID`)