# #1089 – Incorrect prefix key

Tags: mysql

Not sure what I am missing... trying to import a `DB`getting the error that says:

> "ERROR 1089 (HY000) at line 594: Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys":

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `block_content__field_three_wide_header`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `block_content__field_three_wide_header` (
  `bundle` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to',
  `langcode` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language code for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_three_wide_header_value` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `field_three_wide_header_format` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`langcode`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `field_three_wide_header_format` (`field_three_wide_header_format`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Data storage for block_content field field_three_wide…';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `block_content__field_three_wide_header`
--
```

Comment: `field_three_wide_header_format` is varchar(5), but ```KEY `field_three_wide_header_format` (`field_three_wide_header_format`(191))```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is wrong with my SQL here? #1089 - Incorrect prefix key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932281/what-is-wrong-with-my-sql-here-1089-incorrect-prefix-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using invalid length for *key field_three_wide_header_format`(191)*.while declare you use length 5 but in key you use 191 that create the problem. use

```
KEY `field_three_wide_header_format` (`field_three_wide_header_format`(5))
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQLnfef2HHA7nkYwobWFUu/0)